# Is there a permanent solution to fixing an RDP lag issue on MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, mac, remote-desktop, lag

Issue: My RDP has been having weird lagging issues, which have started to happen more and more frequently. The RDP will work perfectly for for a couple hours (closer to an hour recently), and then will suddenly become so slow that it is impossible to do work. I have tracked the issue using PingPlotter ([PingPlotter Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlZEN.png)). If I leave PingPlotter running for a longer time period, the issue will reach a peak, drop suddenly, and then start the "step" pattern again.

Current Solution: The issue is not tied to a particular IP, or final destination, as the issue is resolved when I restart my computer. However, because the issue is happening more frequently, this is quite time-consuming.

Relevant Info: I am working off of a mid-2014 MacBook Pro, and using Microsoft Remote Desktop (Version 10.2.3).

Question: Is there a more permanent solution to this issue, rather than restarting my computer every time? Is the increased frequency of this issue a sign that I may need to purchase a new computer? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Mac RDP clients work in a different way than their Windows counterparts: instead of compressing and sending bitmaps over the network, they rely on repainting the distant desktop and applications with each new keystroke and mouse movement or click. After a while, graphical memory on your machine gets saturated, especially if you like to RDP in fullscreen mode. Try one of those two (preferably the first, since the second isn't developed anymore): https://www.freerdp.com/ or http://cord.sourceforge.net/. I remember that CoRD used to work really well on Snow Leopard, but has since gone defunct.

Comment: 10.2.3 is an old version of RDP client - there have been [many fixes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/mac-whatsnew)  since and the current version doesn't have this issue for me on Catalina.  What version of macOS are you using? Are you constrained from upgrading because of that?

Comment: @lx07 I updated both macOS and RDP. I haven't had any issues since, so that seems to have solved the issue. Thanks for the help!!